# deploy kube-prometheus can not acess grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kube-prometheus-stack

i deploy kube-prometheus on k8s .but i can not access grafana 。
kube-prometheus version: release-0.12

```
k8s version: 
clientVersion:
  buildDate: "2022-12-08T19:58:30Z"
  compiler: gc
  gitCommit: b46a3f887ca979b1a5d14fd39cb1af43e7e5d12d
  gitTreeState: clean
  gitVersion: v1.26.0
  goVersion: go1.19.4
  major: "1"
  minor: "26"
  platform: linux/amd64
kustomizeVersion: v4.5.7
serverVersion:
  buildDate: "2023-01-18T19:15:26Z"
  compiler: gc
  gitCommit: ff2c119726cc1f8926fb0585c74b25921e866a28
  gitTreeState: clean
  gitVersion: v1.25.6
  goVersion: go1.19.5
  major: "1"
  minor: "25"
  platform: linux/amd64
```

i can access granfa by   kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/grafana 3000 -n monitoring

as result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpjYI.png)

i can not access Grafana for http://pod_ip:3000 or http://svc_ip:3000.for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MefAv.png)

I enter other containers and execute the ping command. The ip of grafana fails, but the ip of other pods can.